# Can't get SetTexture to work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty sure this will be an easy fix, but I don't see it. 
I want to change the texture on the material a projector is projecting. 
This is what I have

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ShowPresentation : MonoBehaviour {
    private GameObject SceneProjector;
    private Material proj;
    public Texture2D NewTexture;

    void Start () {
        SceneProjector = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Projector") ;
        proj = SceneProjector.GetComponent<Projector>().material;
        NewTexture = Resources.LoadAssetAtPath ("Assets/Textures/Wood.tga", typeof(Object)) as Texture2D;
        proj.SetTexture("_MainTex", NewTexture);
    }


    void Update () {
        Debug.Log (proj);
        Debug.Log(NewTexture);
        }
}
```

Everything used to be at update but even in Start it won't work. 
The debug logs show that it can find the material and texture, so it has to be something to do with the settexture

Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know what you did but this is the example from unity documentation. you can set it to the script of the object that you want to change its texture. 
_BumpMap is the normal map

```
public Texture bumpMap;
renderer.material.SetTexture("_BumpMap", bumpMap);
```

Comment: issue with that is that I don't seem to have a renderer on the projector. Maybe I'm doing this all wrong, I tried changing the material trough code an that didn't work. Maybe I should get some sleep and try again tomorrow. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Got it! Turns out, I didn't need BumpMap but _ShadowTex :D. Wasn't mentioned at the documentation :)